# Command line tool for UPnP playback operation

Tags: media

I'm running gmediarenderer and BubbleUPnP on a Raspberry Pi which allows me to use the device as a UPnP renderer (all setup using [this tutorial](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLvuSTpIXRAhVWd1AKHahiCtMQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.scphillips.com%2Fposts%2F2014%2F05%2Fplaying-music-on-a-raspberry-pi-using-upnp-and-dlna-v3%2F&usg=AFQjCNEuAJqUWT--lbhXhgBTG6OWYOIX9g&sig2=CLQ3fbvkcXQRGam_3Colxg&bvm=bv.142059868,d.ZWM)). I can issue commands to the Pi by using other devices on the network to enqueue tracks, or play/pause, etc. For example, using [Kinsky](https://oss.linn.co.uk/trac/wiki/Kinsky).

There are certain drawbacks to this setup. Specifically, the need to login using another computer to pause playback or alter the volume can be annoying when, for example, I receive a phone call and need to quickly pause, or if the WiFi goes down, the only way to stop playback is to pull the plug.

I've therefore gotten hold of an infrared receiver and remote that I can use to send commands directly to the Pi, and, in theory, instantly pause playback or change the volume without having to log in via another device on the network.

What I need is a set of commands that can be executed when a button is pressed on the remote, that actually do things like pause, play, skip track, etc. Presumably, these would be simple command line controls. Therefore, I'm currently looking for a command line tool that performs these simple operations.

Is anyone aware of such a tool? Or are there perhaps already commands that can be sent directly to gmediarenderer? I've seen [tools for other systems](http://forum.wdlxtv.com/viewtopic.php?f=&t=1700) that operate over DLNA, but I can't get these to work on gmediarender.